# Excel : Find numbers in a list which when summed total a target number

Tags: excel

Ive got a list of several thousand numbers.

I have a target number which is a sum of some of the list of numbers.

I want to be able to find what numbers in the list, when summed total to the target number.

Eg.

```
List : 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Target : 
5

Result : 
The target could be made from the sum of 1+4, 2+3, 5
```

If there are is no way the target can be achieved from the numbers in the list eg. `list : 10,20 and the Target : 5` then the formula should output "no available matches"

That is a very simple example but in practice there are thousands of numbers in the list and some of the numbers are up to seven digits long.

Is there a formula could be used in excel (or google sheets) that would work this out automatically ? Preferably as a native function rather than VBA / Script.

Answer (score 1):

You request is so complex that there is not a native function, which can do that. In top of it, the result of your function is a whole collection of possibilities (like `[5, 1+4, 2+3]` in your particular case), while Excel functions only generate a single result, which can be placed in a single cell.

In top of this, it's quite a difficult task to program, let me explain you why with some simple examples:

```
List : 1,2,3,4,5
Desired result: 36
=> no way: even when you sum all elements of the list, the result is not large enough.

List : 6,7,8,9,10
Desired result: 5
=> no way: even the smallest element in the list is larger than the result.

List : 1,2,20,21,23
Desired result: 10
=> no way (but how to make a computer see this?)

List : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
Desired result: 119
=> easy as hell: the sum of all numbers of the list is 120, just subtract 1.

List: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
Desired result: 11
=> no way: all numbers in the list are odd, you can't obtain an odd number.
```

As you see, for a human this is fairly simple, but how to get a computer to do this?

Comment: Thanks @dominique for the detailed answer what i guess i should have added to the question is that, if there is no possible match/s then the function should return "no possible matches" or "none" (i have updated the question to reflect this.). With regards to the multiple matching results, although excel could concatenate the multiple matching results into one cell. It could also output an array

Comment: @sam: my answer consists of two separate parts: 1. Your question is far too complex to be handled by "simple" Excel features. 2. Excel functions are not meant to deliver a list of results. In your comment you focus on the second part while the first part of my answer is the main one. For answering your question, programming is needed (and quite some complex programming, if you want to get it calculated at a reasonable speed).